# first or initialize causing forbidden attribute error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having an issue adding new users to my database using first_or_initialize in RoR.

I'm using omniauth-facebook. When I run the following code it gives me a ForbiddenAttributeError.

```
def self.omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = uid
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.firstname = auth.info.first_name
        user.surname = auth.info.last_name
        user.token = auth.credentials.token
        user.expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
        user.save!
    end
end
```

That code is from my User class.